# Firewall rule for IAP traffic added but ssh for GCP server still not working

Tags: nginx, ssh, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I am running a .dev website on GCP. The website is running but whenever I try to access the vm via ssh, it returns "Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed" Code 1006.

I am not too familiar with networking theory so I searched for fixes online and all the help I found suggested the following:

- Add a firewall rule (allow-ingress-from-iap)

  - Target: all instances in the network
  - Filter: IP ranges
  - Ranges: 35.235.240.0/20
  - Protocol: tcp 22

When I checked, the error still persists. So I went ahead and disabled the default ssh firewall rule.

Upon checking again, the error still persists. Any help?

*Other server information:*

- *nginx*
- *PHP 7.4*
- *mariadb database*
- *SSL certificate installed (certbot)*
- *SSL config, redirect http traffic to https*
- *listening to 443*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Upon looking around the GCP instance settings, I discovered the following:

1. Check the status of firewall allowed traffic (sudo ufw status)
2. In my case, only Nginx traffic is allowed.
3. Allow traffic for port 22 by writing a startup script in instance vm. (ufw allow 22)
4. Restart the instance.

I was able to connect via ssh after.